# How to auto-update jar files for hundred hosts?

Tags: java, file, jar

I have a application for monitoring Linux Host, so I have to deploy a Agent for every host, but This causes a problem to update these so many Agent (mainly, a jar file in this agent ).
So is these some simple method to remote update these many jar file  on different hosts ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Java Web Start, handles all this for you.

Comment: +1 For reference, the [tag:java-web-start] [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) has some helpful links.

Comment: Does JWS support this condition? I should first kill the agent process, then update the jar file, and restart this agent process at last . I hope I can update all the agent on a centralized platform, and don't need to access any Linux hosts .

Comment: @Michael Smith Does the agent have to run continuously? If so that's a problem, otherwise JWS checks for updates every time you start the application. You just update the JARs etc at a central server.

Comment: Yes, the Agent should run continuously. and I don't want to restart the agent often. Is there simple way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Easy way is to restart it at the same interval you expect to update the software. Once a week won't kill you, and you won't be (shouldn't be) releasing software more often than that.